# Check few AD computers name by it's part

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find full AD computer name based on it's last 7 digits (names are set as 4 digits + DELL service tag)
I'm using below command to find 1 computer and it works fine but i have to find over 200 so im wondering if it's possible to do it for all servie tags from .txt file? And then export results to csv or Grid view?

> Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "*93PXPV2"' -Properties * | FT Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct an LDAP filter that searches for all name suffixes at once, eg.:

```
(|(name=*93PXPV2)(name=*17GEJK8)(name=*...))
```

Assuming you have the suffixes stored in a txt file, one on each line, you could do something like this:

```
# Read name suffix information from disk
$suffixes = Get-Content path\to\computerNames.txt

# Construct LDAPFilter
$LDAPFilter = '(|{0})' -f -join($suffixes |ForEach-Object { "(name=*${_})" })

# Search for, and export, all the names at once!
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter |Select Name,Enabled,DistinguishedName |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly and save me hours of work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$input_filename = "c:\temp\test.txt"
$shortNames = Get-Content -Path $input_filename
$shortNames | Format-Table

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($shortName in $shortNames)
{
   $result = Get-ADComputer -Filter Name -like ("*" + $shortName) -Properties *
   foreach($computer in $result)
   {
      $table.Add($computer)  | Out-Null
   }
}
$table | Format-Table
```